# Is making LED at 10MHz blinking rate good?

Tags: led, infrared, receiver

I am trying to create a project for transmitting visible light over optical fiber. 
I am planning for a frequency of 10MHz for data transfer. Is a LED(including infrared) good for this blinking rate? Or what alternative I have if I want to use visible/infrared spectrum?

Also what should be the best receiver for this blinking rate? Photo Diode, TSOP(if infrared)

Comment: You can find LEDs that blink at this rate and some are good for 100 MHz. Guess what, read the data sheets on a selection to get an idea.

Comment: They use lasers for 10MHz but this is not trivial. Try something simple, then increment. 10kHz communication is a good start.

Comment: You'll find that "normal" indicator LEDs will appear to become dimmer as the frequency increases above 1MHz or so, due to inductive and capacitive properties of the diode they cannot respond fast enough.  You'll definitely need some specialist emitters and sensors for 10MHz and higher.

Comment: @Wossname: That's what I am asking. :-)  Where do I search for those? Googling it gives non useful info.

Comment: @InQusitive, Try any of these: Farnell, Digikey, Mouser, Arrow, RS... those are the big name parts vendors, any of those will have a good selection.

Comment: There are commercial LED+driver and LVDS communication built into one package for fiber communication. The packaging due to inductance, just like Wossname said.

Answer (score 1):

Sfp will go up to 1Gbps for descent price. And you will not need to arrange fiber mechanics, instead you will use just a common lc connector.

Upd:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_form-factor_pluggable_transceiver

So sfp is a small form factor pluggable transceiver. Maybe for optic cable or for copper cable. Probably is better than inventing a wheel. Also may be very cheap in China.

Comment: It would be good if you could expand the acronym SFP and perhaps include a picture of an SFP transceiver and a link to more info.

Comment: Too lazy for that... Google does it better than me.

Answer (score 0):

> Is making LED at 10MHz blinking rate good?

not sure what you meant by "good" but leds can certainly blink at that kind of rate: there are implementations of "wifi" over leds so it is absolutely doable.

BTW, such led-wifi can be used for lighting concurrently, :)